# Displaying tooltip in standalone program

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I have a `tkinter window` that displays a tooltip, when i am over a button with the mouse. Below is the code for that:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Button

class ToolTip(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, text, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.x = x #root window coordinates
        self.y = y #root window coordinates
        self.dx = dx #differnce to root window
        self.dy = dy #differnce to root window

        def enter(event):
            self.showTooltip()
        def leave(event):
            self.hideTooltip()
        widget.bind('<Enter>', enter)
        widget.bind('<Leave>', leave)
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", leave)

    def showTooltip(self):
        self.tooltipwindow = tw = tk.Toplevel(self.widget)
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1) # window without border and no normal means of closing
        tw.wm_geometry("+{}+{}".format(self.widget.winfo_rootx(), self.widget.winfo_rooty()))
        label = tk.Label(tw, text = self.text, background = "#ffffe0", relief = 'solid', borderwidth = 1)
        label.pack()
        tw.geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.x + self.dx, self.y + self.dy))

    def hideTooltip(self):
        try:
            tw = self.tooltipwindow
            tw.destroy()
            self.tooltipwindow = None
        except:
            pass

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Start')

button = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)
button.pack()
ToolTip(widget=button, text="Quits programm", x=root.winfo_x(), y=root.winfo_y(), dx=80, dy=55)

root.mainloop()
```

As long as I run the whole thing in the `Pycharm environment` it works fine. But when I convert the code to a standalone program using `py2app`, the tooltip is no longer displayed. Below is the code for the `setup` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```